# turns based on threads lead to unexpected deadlock

Tags: multithreading, tic-tac-toe, turn

the program is a simple tic tac toe game ( the game logic is already tested )
im supposed to let each player be its own thread yet i can not figure out why im getting a deadlock in my situation

each player has a boolean called myTurn which is controlled by a static game manager object
the run method is as follows

```
    public void run()
{
    
    while(true)
    {
        if(myTurn )
        {
            playTurn();
            Game.g.switchTurn();
        }
    }
    
}
```

my playTurn method is as follows:

```
    private synchronized void playTurn()
{
    
    System.out.println(board);
    getTurn();
    
    board.incTurnCount();
    Game.g.checkGameEnd(type);
    
    
    
}
```

and finally the switch turns method

```
public void switchTurn()
{
    p1.setMyTurn(!p1.isMyTurn()); 
    p2.setMyTurn(!p2.isMyTurn()); 
}
```

the main method

```
public class Game {

public static GameLogicHandler g;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MenusHandler m = new MenusHandler();
    Board b = new Board(3);
    HumanPlayer p1 = new HumanPlayer("a", true, b);
    HumanPlayer p2 = new HumanPlayer("b", false, b);
    g = new GameLogicHandler(p1, p2, b);
    
    p1.start();
    p2.start();
    System.out.println(b);
    
    

}
```

}

Game.g has an instance of p1 and p2, while debugging they do change and work yet in run time im getting deadlocked

the idea is that each turn the game object changes the turn state on both players enabling them to enter the if condition regarding their own turn. p1s myTurn is started as true

Answer (score 0):

my issue was not putting the part inside my run method in a synchronized block. new code (which works) looks like this

```
public void run()
{
    
    while(true)
    {
        synchronized (board) {
            if(myTurn && !board.isGameFinished() )
            {
                playTurn();
                Game.g.switchTurn();
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```